# Unity: AnimationClip generated with code not playing, Manual created AnimationClip does

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an augmented Reality project in Unity where the user will be able to see an animated sprite on their phone when pointing the camera at a certain image.

The Sprite will be created by a belgian comic book artist and will be quite lengthy. To make my life easier I wanted to create an editor script that takes all the sprites from the Resources/Sprite folder and creates an AnimationClip.

```
    Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("sprite");
    AnimationClip animClip = new AnimationClip();
    animClip.frameRate = 25; // fps


    EditorCurveBinding spriteBinding = new EditorCurveBinding();
    spriteBinding.type = typeof(SpriteRenderer);
    spriteBinding.path = "";
    spriteBinding.propertyName = "m_Sprite";

    ObjectReferenceKeyframe[] spriteKeyFrames = new ObjectReferenceKeyframe[sprites.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < (sprites.Length); i++)
    {
        spriteKeyFrames[i] = new ObjectReferenceKeyframe();
        spriteKeyFrames[i].time = i / animClip.frameRate;
        spriteKeyFrames[i].value = sprites[i];
    }
    AnimationUtility.SetObjectReferenceCurve(animClip, spriteBinding, spriteKeyFrames);

    AnimationClipSettings animClipSett = new AnimationClipSettings();
    animClipSett.loopTime = true;

    AnimationUtility.SetAnimationClipSettings(animClip, animClipSett);

    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(animClip, "assets/generated.anim");
    AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
    AssetDatabase.Refresh();
```

This works, an AnimationClip is created but when using it in the Animation Panel nothing happens.

I made the same Animation manually to see if that would work and it does.

The blue bar in the animation panel moves though

*Animator Panel showing the generated AnimationClip:*

[image]

The only noticable difference I've found (besides one of them playing and the other one doesn't) is that the generated clip's Length changes to 0 after trying to run it's animation

*The Sprite Object and inspector:*

[image]

I'be been trying to find what I'm doing wrong for half a day now without getting a single step closer.

I'd like to thank who answers on this question in advance.

Greetings,

Maethorian

Comment: Hi Maethorian! It is also recommended to insert code as text and format it using question editor. Please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Change `spriteKeyFrames[i].time = i / animClip.frameRate;` to `spriteKeyFrames[i].time = i`

Comment: Same problems, wont that make the animation Length way too long?

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question. It's an alternate way to animate sprite but it  does not have anything to do with your question(creating animationclip).

Comment: Add `AnimationUtility.SetAnimationType(animClip, ModelImporterAnimationType.Generic);` and `animClip.wrapMode = WrapMode.Once;` before calling `AnimationUtility.SetObjectReferenceCurve`. Let me know if that fixes your problem.

Comment: `AnimationUtility.SetAnimationType(animClip, ModelImporterAnimationType.Generic);` is Deprecated and no longer works.